# Log4j RollingFileAppender rolls on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: java, windows, logging, log4j

I am setting up a standard logrotate-style Log4j logger for my Java application. For this purpose, I have several `RollingFileAppender`s (one for each "sub-unit" of the project) that output to a log file in the application's folder. I have set the size limit before rolling to 100MB. On Linux, this works perfectly and logs are rolled over after reaching 100 MB.

However, on Windows the log file just keeps growing and does not roll over.

I have read in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410984/log4j-rollingfileappender-unable-to-roll-file) that multiple Java applications on the same JVM (or multiple JVMs) using the same log file will cause Log4j to fail the rollover since multiple processes have file descriptors open to that file - but in my case this is clearly not an issue since I am using *a single* Java application on *a single* JVM.

Note that the log file is not open in any other process.

Can anyone offer more insight into what might cause this/suggest a workaround?

Comment: Could you please post your related log4j configuration.

Comment: I am dynamically setting up the `RollingFileAppender`s at runtime - I need this in order to make the log file path be relative to the installation path of the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [The Complete Log4j Manual](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2084854.The_Complete_Log4j_Manual) by *Ceki Gülcü*:

> **Can multiple appenders running in the same JVM log to the same file?**
>
> The answer is no. For performance and other technical reasons, log4j does not perform any synchronization between appenders. Having multiple appenders in the *same* JVM logging to the same file is not much different from having multiple appenders in *different* JVMs logging to the same file.

Given the above, one solution is to create a single `RollingFileAppender` and attach it to the root logger, i.e.

```
// Set up the RollingFileAppender
RollingFileAppender rollingAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
rollingAppender.setFile(logfileURL);

... (set up your appender here)

// Attach it to the root logger
LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(rollingAppender);
```

Log4j will now have no multiple-file-descriptor problems and will log everything from all sources to a single log file.