# Regarding log4j working in java application

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j in my java application. My log4j property file is as follows

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=file_path
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=500MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n​
```

Problem I am facing is maxfilesize is defined as 500 MB, so my understanding is that after 500 MB a new log file should be generated but in my case new file is getting generated only after server restart. If I don't resstart my server, logs get accumulated in the same file even after 500 MB limit. How to resolve it? Is it the normal behaviour of log4j or there is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you

Comment: I am talking about normal log file which get generated by log4j

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410984/log4j-rollingfileappender-unable-to-roll-file